# create parameter from partial listbox item

Tags: c#, sql

I have a listbox with items that are a concatenation of two columns (Game_ID+"- "+Name) in a different listbox. So each listbox item looks like:

> 1- Game#1
>
> 2- Game#2
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> 10- Game#10
>
> ...
>
> 100- Game#100

I need to know how to make the parameter only the game_ID portion of the list item. So basically I need just the portion to the left of the hyphen.

```
    string newPGame = "INSERT INTO admin.promo_games(promo_ID, Game_ID) VALUES(@PID, @GameID)"
    SqlCommand insGames = new SqlCommand(newPGame, misc);

    insGames.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", txtID.Text);
    insGames.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameID", lstSelGames.SelectedValue);
       foreach (string item in lstSelGames.Items)
          {
             insGames.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
```

Comment: Why not have the SelectedValue (the behind scenes value) of the select list just be that value, so when you get it from the form, it is what you need.  The display text can be whatever you want and then you dont have to parse it.

Comment: You may want to [stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Also `SqlCommand` is `IDisposable` so should be in a `using` block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Substring` and `int.Parse` to parse the number:

```
var itemText = lstSelGames.SelectedValue.ToString();
var numberString = itemText.Substring( itemText.IndexOf("-") );
var number = int.Parse(numberString);
```

A better solution would be to create a class that represents an item in the list and then use a strongly typed instance here:

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return Id + Name;
    }
}
```

Then `SelectedValue` will actually be of type `Game`:

```
var game = (Game)lstSelGames.SelectedValue;
//use game.Id
```